# Set connection timeout to olingo request

Tags: android, odata, olingo

I am using olingo client android 4.0.0 library to communicate with my backend which has implemented OData protocol from android client.
I want to set request timeout to my olingo request.
Also I want to disable retry on connection failure.

```
ODataClient oDataClient = ODataClientFactory.getV4();
ODataEntityCreateRequest<ODataEntity> req = oDataClient.getCUDRequestFactory()
                            .getEntityCreateRequest(uri, oDataEntity);
```

I want to add timeout and disable connection retry for it.

Comment: share your code.

Answer (score 2):

After going through the code of Olingo client library came across a workaround for this.

`ODataClient` has a `Configuration` property, which has `HttpClientFactory` parameter. I had to create a class which extended `DefaultHttpClientFactory` and override it's methods to update `HttpClient` with timeout and retry policy changes.

Complete code is as below.

```
private class RequestRetryHttpClientFactory extends DefaultHttpClientFactory {
        private final int HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 2 * 60 * 1000; 

        @Override
        public org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient create(HttpMethod method, URI uri) {
            final HttpRequestRetryHandler myRetryHandler = new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean retryRequest(IOException e, int i, HttpContext httpContext) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "RETRY REQUEST");
                    return false;
                }
            };
            final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = super.create(method, uri);
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);

            httpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(myRetryHandler);
            return httpClient;
        }
    }
```

I added this to my oDataClient as bellow.

```
ODataClient oDataClient = ODataClientFactory.getV4();
oDataClient.getConfiguration().setHttpClientFactory(new RequestRetryHttpClientFactory());
ODataEntityCreateRequest<ODataEntity> req = oDataClient.getCUDRequestFactory()
                            .getEntityCreateRequest(uri, oDataEntity);
```

I hope this will help someone.